# Display all days(dates) between two dates in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to use select "**From**" and "**To**" dates from datepicker and display all dates in between, in tabular form using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to calculate no. of days. Hope it helps

```js
function daysCalculator(date1, date2) {
  var d1 = new Date(date1);
  var d2 = new Date(date2);
  var days = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
  days = parseInt((((days / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24)
  return days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
 function getDates(fromDate, toDate) {
        var dateArray = [];
        var nextDate = fromDate;
        while (nextDate <= toDate) {
            dateArray.push( nextDate );
            nextDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return dateArray;
    }
```