# How to show dates In cards between two selected dates in Ionic 2/3 and angular 3/4

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm very new in ionic, and trying to calculate difference between two dates and this dates will display in cards. dates selection limit is only up-to 7 days means if from date is 25/03/2018 then to date is 31/03/2018 or before to date. I found number of questions like this 
      [Display all days(dates) between two dates in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624097/display-all-daysdates-between-two-dates-in-angularjs) but cant understand how to write code. i'm trying to get screen like in image. and when i click on + sign it opens card fields   [image]

I'm able to write only .html file code for dates

```
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked [style.color]="titlelabel" color="titlelabel" style="margin-top:10px">Travel From Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime placeholder="dd/mm/yy" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" class="ion-input" [(ngModel)]="fromdate"> {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-datetime>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked [style.color]="titlelabel" color="titlelabel" style="margin-top:10px">Travel To Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime  placeholder="dd/mm/yy" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" class="ion-input" [(ngModel)]="todate">{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

Please help me

Update:

.html file

```
   <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked [style.color]="titlelabel" color="titlelabel" style="margin-top:10px">From Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime placeholder="dd/mm/yy" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" class="ion-input" [(ngModel)]="fromdate" (ionChange)="fromDateChanged($event)">{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked [style.color]="titlelabel" color="titlelabel" style="margin-top:10px">Travel To Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime placeholder="dd/mm/yy" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" class="ion-input" [(ngModel)]="todate" (ionChange)="toDateChanged($event)">{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>



  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let date of datesForCards">

    <ion-item>

      <ion-card class="ion-card">

        <ion-card-content class="ion-card-content">

          <h5 style="color:red">
            {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}

            <ion-icon style="float: right;" ios="ios-add-circle" md="md-add-circle" (click)="onButtonClick()">
            </ion-icon>
          </h5>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-sliding>
```

.ts file

```
    fromDate: Date;
    toDate: Date;
    datesForCards = [];

   fromDateChanged(fromDate: Date) {
       this.datesForCards = [];
       if (this.toDate) {
       this.datesForCards = this.getDatesBetween(fromDate, this.toDate);
       console.log(this.datesForCards);
    }
  }

   toDateChanged(toDate: Date) {
        this.datesForCards = [];
        if (this.fromDate) {
        this.datesForCards = this.getDatesBetween(this.fromDate, toDate);
     }
   }

  getDatesBetween(from: Date, to: Date): Date[] {

    console.log("dates");
    let year = from.getFullYear();
    let month = from.getMonth();
    let day = from.getDate();
    let dates = [from];
    while (dates[dates.length - 1] < to) {
       dates.push(new Date(year, month, ++day));
       console.log(dates);
   }
      return dates;  
  }
```

when i add to date does not add cards and console doesn't print anything

Comment: You can use `(ngModelChange)` or `(ionChange)` to trigger a function whenever form or to date is changed. In the function generate the new list of 5 dates.

Comment: do you have any example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough code to illustrate the idea. This code is not tested.

```
<ion-datetime 
    placeholder="dd/mm/yy" 
    displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
    class="ion-input"
    [ngModel]="fromDate"
    (ngModelChange)="fromDateChanged($event)"> {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-datetime>
<ion-datetime 
    placeholder="dd/mm/yy" 
    displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" 
    class="ion-input"
    [ngModel]="toDate"
    (ngModelChange)="toDateChanged($event)"> {{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-datetime>
<div *ngFor="date of datesForCards">
    <div>{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</div>
</div>
```

---

<kbd>component.ts</kbd>

```
fromDateChanged(fromDate: Date){
    this.datesForCards = [];
    if(this.toDate) {
        this.datesForCards = this.getDatesBetween(fromDate, this.toDate);
    }
}

toDateChanged(fromDate: Date){
    this.datesForCards = [];
    if(this.fromDate) {
        this.datesForCards = this.getDatesBetween(this.fromDate, toDate);
    }
}

getDatesBetween(from: Date, to: Date) : Date[] {
    let year = from.getFullYear();
    let month = from.getMonth();
    let day = from.getDate();
    let dates = [from];
    while(dates[dates.length-1] < to) {
      dates.push(new Date(year, month, ++day));
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the code as you tried it. Also as mentioned, this is not a working code that you can copy/paste, you will have to try it in these lines.